# Any reason why my cell value isn't being truncated?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here's what I'm trying to do in my Winforms DataGridView:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 1)
    {
        string tmpValue = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);

        if (tmpValue.Length >= 3)
        {
            //At thsi point, I'm 100% sure that tmpValue has "253" as it's value.
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = tmpValue.Substring(0, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, the value isn't changed of the cell I leave.

If I type 258 in the cell and leave, it should have 25.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to cause validation to occur for it to take place.  At the end, add `this.Validate();`

You might also want to try using the [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) event instead, since this even is fired after the cell leave and validation events.

Comment: I just checked, I have to leave the cell, go back into it, and then leave again and **then** is works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they mean `Invalidate`?

Comment: @Sergio - nice, I was just writing that.  Glad you found the answer

Answer (score 0):

perhaps: dataGridView1.DataBind()